# JavaScript TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, queryselector

i want to change the padding of class cmp-container__content

- this cmp-container__content class is inside **iframe **

const element= document.querySelector('iframe').contentDocument;
element.body.querySelector(".div.container.cmp-container.cmp-container__content").style.padding="30px";